# What replaces Phrase in itext7?

Tags: itext

The itext 5 code in our codebase uses "Phrase" as below. Is there any equivalent in itext 7? I think the substitute for "Chunk" could be "Text" in itext 7 and I know the workaround for Font. But couldn't find anything for Phrase.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;

public class PdfUtils {

    public static void setFont(Phrase phrase, Font font) {
        if (phrase == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (Object object : phrase) {
            if (object instanceof Chunk) {
                Chunk chunk = (Chunk) object;
                chunk.setFont(font);
            }

        }
        phrase.setFont(font);
    }
}
```

Comment: riptutorial [compiled Stackoverflow answers that compare 5 and 7](https://riptutorial.com/itext), that you might find useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Paragraph](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Paragraph.html).

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.setFont(font);
Text text = new Text("test");
paragraph.add(text);
```

Comment: just pointing to the [latest API version](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Paragraph.html), as of this writing (7.1.13).